# How to show navigation drawer on every fragment with back arrow icon (default back arrow icon) in toolbar?

Tags: android

I haved created navigation drawer in an app. Now I want that navigation drawer show on every fragment with back arrow icon except first fragment (home screen) in toolbar similar to Gmail app.How can I do that?

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Could you add some code with what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is to implement the drawer in a base activity class that you extend from.  The base activity should also include a layout container for inflating or injecting fragments.  This way the drawer is also ever present whether you are swapping fragments or changing activities.  Putting a drawer on the fragment would defeat the fragments purpose of being a reusable screen component with other fragments.